# Scroll to different sections on same page

Tags: html

I am having 2 pages contact.html and about.html and both of these pages have been called in index.html. So my index.html shows both the parts contact and about. I have a section on about.html where i have written a text contact which a link and it should scroll to down to the contact section. How can I implement this

Answer (score 1):

Give an id to your section. For example `contact` and than refer it with `a` tag.

```html
<a href="#contact">Contact Me</a>

<section id="contact"> -- CONTENT -- </section>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't helped.

Comment: Without providing your code. This is the only way I can help.

Comment: is there any otherway by javascript or jquery ??

Comment: When you can do something with html or CSS, it is better to do it. But it should madeable with javascript too.

Comment: By using id as you suggested it scrolls down  but it comes to the top again within a second, Also the id gets displayed in the url. And second time the link is unclickable. Why Is this happening ??